# Why does my looping instruction to input values for a character array of 6 elements stop after 3 inputs?

Tags: android, c, debugging

I'm new to C and programming in general. I'm stuck wondering why this thing is happening. Basically, I wrote this simple program to input a 6 character array from the user, and to print the same out. I'm using CPPDroid on my Android phone to compile and execute the code;

```
#include"stdio.h"
int main()
{
    char c[6];
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&c[i]);
    }
    for(int j=0;j<=5;j++)
    {
        printf("%c",c[j]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the first loop simply exits out before the rest of the elements are filled. I'd get an output like this (I entered a,b,s as the first 3 elements):

```
a
b
s
a
b
s
```

It just simply only takes 3 elements rather than 6, and prints them back. What's going on?

My apologies if this is a well known issue. I'm not familiar with terms used in programming much, so it's not easy for me to search for questions.

Comment: Three characters plus three newlines = six inputs. Try replacing `"%c"` with `"%c "` (with the added space) in your `scanf()` statement.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Cool! That makes it works now.  Can you please make that an answer with an explanation as to why it works that way, I'd really appreciate it. :)

Comment: This has probably been asked loads of times already. [The documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scanf&sektion=3) explains how scanf works. In particular, *"White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input."* On reflection, you should probably change `"%c "` to `" %c"` so your program doesn't hang after the last input.

Comment: It is almost always wrong to use _trailing_ whitespace in `scanf()` format strings, since this tells `scanf()` to match whitespace characters until a non-whitespace character (or `EOF`) is encountered. This causes trouble with interactive input. Instead use _leading_ whitespace to consume initial whitespace characters (such as newline characters). Often an even better option is to clear the input stream with `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {continue;}`, which clears all characters in the input stream so long as there is at least a newline present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type in:

```
a
b
s
```

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke is counted as its own character (the newline character, `'\n'`), so you end up storing the following in `c`: `['a', '\n', 'b', '\n', 's', '\n']`.

If you want to consume the newline, you can include it in the `scanf()` call; something like this:

```
scanf("\n%c",&c[i]);
```

Comment: Oh my god. I never knew that a newline would *actually* be considered a character. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This sparks a question now. Should I type "abs" without spaces or enters" then it would be considered as I wish to would it?

Comment: Yep, try it out - but of course you'd need to type 6 characters before your program prints them out to you.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers and comments mentioned it right. I will just add one more thing. Earlier the `\n` were also taken as input by the `scanf`. As a result 
your loop ended and still the characters you desired were not read.

#### why the solution `scanf("%c ",..)` works?

> Now, the trailing one is telling `scanf()` to skip any trailing
>   whitespace after the character input. It therefore keeps reading input
>   until it sees something that is not whitespace or the end of the
>   stream.

Also as pointed out, the leading white space would also let you achieve the same thing with the added benefit of having a smooth interactive input.

To give you an idea of what I mean I would give an excample:

```
int n,m;
scanf("%d ",&n);
printf("n is %d\n",n);
printf("Give 2nd number\n");
scanf("%d ",&m);
printf("m is %d\n",m);
```

So now you start giving input.
<kbd>1</kbd>
<kbd>Enter</kbd>
Now you expect so see the output `n is 1`. But it seems like it stopped.

You again type <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
Now you see the output: `n is 1`. Then you see the output

```
n is 1
6<enter>
Give 2nd number
m is 2
```

That's what I meant when asked to avoid the trailing whitespace.

Comment: Trailing whitespace in `scanf()` format strings is usually a mistake which causes trouble with interactive input. Use leading whitespace instead.